# Extjs pagingtoolbar how to center display message

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In ext paging toolbar is there a way to center the display message

```
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            height: 26,
            width: 360,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: '{0} - {1} of {2}',
            border: false,
            store: 'myStore'
            dock: 'bottom'
```

I want to center the displayMsg but I haven't how to.

Answer (score 1):

Default the paging toolbar adds a tbfill element when displayInfo is true. To center your text you can add another tbfill at the end.

```
grid.down('pagingtoolbar').add({xtype:'tbfill'});
```

This will center the text in the empty part of the toolbar, if you want to center it in the whole toolbar i think you need to calculate the width of the first tbfill and then set it.